# Rails: run code ignoring binding.pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, binding, breakpoints, pry

I often use the pry-byebug gem to put breakpoints in my code using

```
binding.pry
```

However, during debugging (say after making a slight change) I often want to run the entire code/spec without any breakpoints for that one time.

Is there an option to do that ?. I am looking for something like

```
bundle exec rspec '--ignore-pry' spec/controller/my_controller.rb
```

Comment: I am not sure about a pry option, but I can think of an easy way to do this easily using git stash, in case you are using version control. `git stash` will remove all those binding.pry statements, and then you can make your changes, and execute code. In case you want those breakpoints again, just use `git stash apply`.

Comment: git stash would also stash my code changes in the current branch along with stashing binding.pry statements.

Comment: I am suggesting you follow an order similar to: (1) All code committed (2) Add binding.pry to debug (3) git stash (4) change code (5) git stash apply in case you want the binding.pry statements back. This is just a sort of workaround. Thought it could help in case there isn't an option for doing what you are asking for. You could always commit locally (bindin.pry statements), revert, and then reset to origin, to take advantage of git while debugging an issue. #justSaying

Comment: I would find this very helpful as well. Seems like a great open source contribution opportunity.

Comment: You can also use `disable-pry` when the first breakpoint is hit to ignore all future breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR use DISABLE_PRY=1 env variable**

I had exactly the same question and I found this https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/spec/pry_spec.rb#L29

basically you just run

```
DISABLE_PRY=1 bundle exec rspec spec/controller/my_controller.rb
```

and you're good. Tested on this vestion of pry modules

```
$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep pry    
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
    pry (0.10.4)
    pry-byebug (3.4.1)
      pry (~> 0.10)
    pry-doc (0.10.0)
      pry (~> 0.9)
    pry-rails (0.3.4)
      pry (>= 0.9.10)
    pry-rescue (1.4.4)
      pry
    pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
      pry (>= 0.9.11)
```

Comment: That info is now in the wiki.
https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Environment-Variables